# AWS ECR how to restrict retagging except for latest tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ecr

I want restrict retagging except for latest tag in AWS ECR.
It is very hard if some developers pushs  image with same tag for debugging.
So I would like to allow only "latest" tag to be retagged. But not for different docker image versions to same tag name.
How to to do it?

Thanks
-prakash

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with ECR today. You can either [enable immutability for tags](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/image-tag-mutability.html) (which would include "latest" being immutable) or you must allow all tags to be mutable. There are no other options. However, there is a [request on the ECR roadmap](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/878) for this.

The only way you might be able to get what you want today is to enforce this scheme after-the-fact when pushes are made to ECR by responding to [ECR events via EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ecr-eventbridge.html). For example, you might subscribe a lambda function to ECR push events. That lambda, in principle, could keep track of image tags and undo a tag push for any existing tag other than latest and perhaps remove the offending pushed image (if it would become untagged as the result of removing the tag).

Pseudo code for such a lambda might be:

```py
def on_event(event, context):
    tag = event['detail']['image-tag']
    repository = event['detail']['repository-name']
    digest = event['detail']['image-digest']

    existing_tags = get_existing_tags(repository)
    # check if a tag has been overwritten by this push event
    if tag != 'latest' and tag in existing_tags:
        # revert the change using our existing records
        previous_image_digest_for_tag = existing_tags[tag].digest
        tag_image(previous_image_digest_for_tag, tag)
        remove_if_untagged(repository, digest) #  optional
    else:  # the tag is new or 'latest'
        # just record this for future enforcement
        update_existing_tags(repository, tag, digest)
    return
```